# Generate Android images that are not icon sized

Tags: android, drawable

I have a set of 4 images I plan to display at the first launch of my app inside of a ViewPager. Each of them is 1MB, so that's 4MB total

I want these images to be shown for any density screen.

- Where should I place these images?
- In which size?
- Will duplication increase the size of my app?
- Maybe a more efficient way to do it? (one location for these drawables)

The closest I've found is http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ but it's only for icons

Thanks!

Comment: that site is not ONLY for icons, if you use http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example you can set your required size

Comment: never saw that option. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1.2. Location: **/res/drawable**. You can have many version of those images and place them in different folder: **drawable-hdpi**, **drawable-ldpi**... For better result, please read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Q3. Duplication will definitely increase the size of your app. But common users will possibly ignore its size is not ridiculously big.

Q4. You can store only one image for every screen size, but you need more coding work to scale the drawable to fit the screen of different device. For better result please read: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html